# SQL - Select where record-set does not contain a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am not sure the title reflects what I am searching for accurately.

I have a header table, and a lines table. For each header, there can be multiple line records.

If the lines table doesn't contain the line value for a header record, I want to return that header record.

**Example:**

Header Table -

```
| ID | xyz...|
|  1 |  abc  |
|  2 |  abc  |
```

Lines Table -

```
| LineID | HeaderID | xyz...|
| 1      |    1     | abc   |
| 2      |    1     | abc   |
| 3      |    1     | abc   |
| 3      |    2     | abc   |
| 4      |    2     | abc   |
| 5      |    2     | abc   |
```

In this case, I am looking to return Header Record 2 if I search for the record that doesn't contain a line ID of 1 or 2.

I can't think of the query for the life of me, even though I know it's staring me right in the face.

When I think of queries to try, I will post them to show my workings, but I am hoping someone has an answer for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `NOT EXISTS` will do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM Header h
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Lines l
    WHERE
        l.HeaderID = h.ID
        AND l.LineID IN(1, 2)
)
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/479263)</kbd>

Comment: Perfect, thank you. +1 for a simple and concise query, I thought it would have been much more convoluted than that. I have to admit, my last attempt was getting there, I just didn't think to add the 'AND l.LineID' and was selecting the ID, instead of '1'. Out of curiousity, why is it 'SELECT 1'?

Comment: @DeeKayy90, the columns in the `SELECT` in the `NOT EXISTS` is not evaluated afaik. You can replace it with `1/0` and it still will not error out.

Answer (score 1):

Query:
**[LINK](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/479268)**

```
SELECT h.*
FROM Header h
LEFT JOIN Lines l
  ON l.HeaderID = h.ID
  AND l.LineID IN(1, 2)
WHERE l.HeaderID is null
```

Comment: I've upvoted this because I like to know multiple ways to achieve a task, nice! Thanks!